# Locate an ever changing element (IDs keep changing)

Tags: c#, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Lets say I have a website with elements where the IDs are regenerated every time a new release has been deployed. My web element locator (below) changes and no longer works. Id is the only unique field.

```
[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "select[id^='View_29_'][id$='_N_19610']")]
private IWebElement _wccType;
```

I have about a hundred of these elements and am not sure how to reduce maintenance. These elements are all in tables. I'll provide an example.

```
<TBODY>
    <TR id=View_29_R_0_V_29_N_1157>
        <TD ondblclick=EditView(2231,2,this); id=View_29_R_0_V_29_N_1157_E_2231 colSpan=2 haschanged="true" Isview="true" ContainerID="View_29_R_0_V_29_N_1157" ObjectID="-1" ContextPath="" ViewID="2231" TypeName="Event" Dynamic="true" ParentViewID="View_29_R_0_V_29"></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR class=ALT_DETAIL_ROW_EDIT>
        <TD class=DETAIL_LABEL_CELL_EDIT width="25%" align=left tpfx="lbl_cell_">
            <SPAN ondblclick=EditNode(19610,2,this); title="" class=FIELD_LABEL tpfx="lbl_">Type</SPAN>
        </TD>
        <TD width="75%" align=left tpfx="cell_">
            <DIV id=C_View_29_R_0_V_29_N_1157_E_2231_N_19610 tpfx="cont_">
                <SELECT onchange=SetIsDirty(this,View_29_R_0_V_29_N_1157_E_2231,this.value); id=View_29_R_0_V_29_N_1157_E_2231_N_19610 style="OVERFLOW: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 11px; HEIGHT: 20px; WIDTH: 100%" nullval="0">
                    <OPTION selected value=0></OPTION>
                    <OPTION title="Anonymous" value=1>Anonymous</OPTION>
                    <OPTION title="8" value=3>8</OPTION>
                    <OPTION title="7" value=5>7</OPTION>
                    <OPTION title="6" value=4>6</OPTION>
                    <OPTION title="5" value=6>5</OPTION>
                    <OPTION title="4" value=8>4</OPTION>
                    <OPTION title="3" value=9>3</OPTION>
                    <OPTION title="2" value=7>2</OPTION>
                    <OPTION title="1" value=10>1</OPTION>
                    <OPTION title="1" value=2>1</OPTION>
                </SELECT>
            </DIV>
        </TD>
    </TR>
</TBODY>
```

So what I'm thinking if all the Ids are changing, locate the 'label' which is TD above the element and then using xpath add a +1 to the td?

That maybe long winded way of doing it but other than doing an whole xpath tree (almost 30 divs and tr and td down) I am stuck on how to locate the element.

Comment: I use the same approach as yours. Sometimes we have to use XPath to get parent element. However, the proper solution is adding class for the element. For instance, `<SELECT onchange=SetIsDirty(this,View_29_R_0_V_29_N_1157_E_2231,this.value); id=View_29_R_0_V_29_N_1157_E_2231_N_19610 style="OVERFLOW: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 11px; HEIGHT: 20px; WIDTH: 100%" nullval="0" class="style wccType">`, so you can find it by css selector `select[class$='wccType']`.

Comment: 3rd party application, we have no way of influencing the way they code.

Comment: You need to find invariant features (one or several) inside or around the `<select>` element you want, and then "walk" up or down the document tree with XPath. It may be difficult (or impossible, even) to do with CSS selectors. Is there something that you are certain will be there before (or after) the select, e.g. text content, class, another attribute of another element? If so, you can translate that into XPath predicates

Comment: Given that you show only a small snippet of the code, your question is impossible to answer. You would need to show a representative sample where it is evident what the regularities are and which parts "keep changing", hence are unreliable.